# Need help for syntax highlighting after empty tags <> </> in JSX files

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, ide, jsx

I have tried the `Javascript React` extension for highlighting JSX syntax. The highlighter does not seem to work after `<>{text}</>` and the file looks like the screenshot below.

The part that appears to be completely blue does not seem to be affected by the syntax highlighter.

[image: Extension does not seem to work for <code><></></code>]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the linter is detecting something wrong with the code. You CAN'T use `React.Fragments` (AKA `<> </>`) as you would use a `div`. It can only be used as the outermost wrapper. Like so:

GOOD:

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <>
      // Rest of JSX
    </>

  )
}
```

WRONG:

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <>Hola</>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: The code is perfectly correct @niconiahi. Pretty sure that's not the reason.